# Unable to Determine Swift Version for the Following Pods Error

Tags: swift, algolia

I am trying to use Algolia for iOS. SWIFT_VERSION is not found for the Pod and throwing an error

Disclaimer, Algolia put out a podsec that does include the SWIFT_VERSION so I am able to proceed forward  but wanted to know for the future if I run into the following error again

For the old pod, I followed the instructions here

https://cocoapods.org/pods/InstantSearchClient

I received this error
Unable to determine swift version for the following pods:

‘InstantSearchClient-library’ does not specify a Swift version and none of the
targets ( ‘Pods’ ) integrating it have the ‘SWIFT_VERSION’ attribute set. Please
contact the author or set the ‘SWIFT_VERSION’ attribute in at least one of the targets that inegrate this pod

StackOverflow had the following suggestions which did not work for me

use a pre_install
[error: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'Starscream')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432520/error-swift-version-5-0-is-unsupported-supported-versions-are-3-0-4-0-4-2)

set the ENV['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5' at the top of the Podfile
['Unable to determine Swift version for the following pod" - Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58691345/unable-to-determine-swift-version-for-the-following-pod-error)

Set the SWIFT_VERSION in code ( I received an error message that the variable SWIFT_VERSION ) was already in use

Here is my code:

```
ENV['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5'

platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'InstantSearchClient', '~> 7.0'

target 'contacts' do

  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  use_frameworks!

  project 'contacts'

  # Pods for contacts

  target 'contactsTests' do

    inherit! :search_paths

    # Pods for testing

  end



  target 'contactsUITests' do

    # Pods for testing

  end



pre_install do |installer|

     installer.analysis_result.specifications.each do |s|
        if s.name == 'InstantSearchClient' 
            s.swift_version = '5.0'

        end

    end

  end

end
```